# Exception when you are suppose to enter something in user input, but hit the enter/return key instead

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I am writing a piece of code in JAVA that needs to handle every possible input. I am stuck on how to throw an exception or handle the case when user do not enter anything but just hit a enter/return key instead.

Comment: Can you check for blank or null string values?

Comment: I just tried, it is not working:( JAVA even allows you to enter input after hitting enter/return key.

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `Scanner#next` instead of `Scanner#nextLine` method. The following code prints 'empty' line for the first input, but for the next one it waits till a non-whitespace input is provided.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("NextLine = " + s);
        s = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Next = " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: True, I was using Scanner.nextInt() the whole time. Thank you so much! Really appreciated.